# How To Access Telegram @wallet In Telethon

Tags: telethon

"Hello everyone, I hope you are all doing well. I have a question: I want to access a Telegram wallet with Telethon. Is that possible? Or is there any other alternative? You can see a screenshot of the Telegram wallet here: [telegram @wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erQyM.png)"

I have tried using Selenium, and it didn't meet my expectations because it's quite heavy. My goal is to send money automatically on Telegram @wallet.